# Implement partial method to login to Soap Service

Tags: soap, .net-6.0

I have problems logging in to old style Soap Service using NET 6.0. If I use 4.8 the login process is straightforward. But the generated code from http://media.atg.se:80/info/PartnerInfoService/version11?WSDL differs between 6.0 and 4.8. In 6.0 I get this "todo" from the generated code:

```cs
public partial class PartnerInfoServicePortClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ATGAIS.PartnerInfoServicePort>, ATGAIS.PartnerInfoServicePort
{        
    /// <summary>
    /// Implement this partial method to configure the service endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceEndpoint">The endpoint to configure</param>
    /// <param name="clientCredentials">The client credentials</param>
    public static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(string serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);

    // ...
    // more generated methods
    // ...
}
```

I just can't figure out HOW to implement it. The site requires `ClientCredentials` which I don't know how to set in 6.0. For 4.8 it was very simple as follows:

```cs
var partnerInfoService = new PartnerInfoService();

// Log in with credentials
try
{
    partnerInfoService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($@"Error: {ex.Message}");
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it says you should implement the *ConfigureEndpoint* method, but for that you should create a new class which inherits from *PartnerInfoServicePortClient*, and... this is so boring...

So the easy way is convert this partial method into a real method, and add the code of the method according to your needs. What I mean is replacing this line:

```cs
public static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(string serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);
```

with this line:

```cs
public static void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials)
{ 
}
```

As an example, I use this code to modify the configuration:

```cs
static public void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials)
{            
    var httpBinding = serviceEndpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;
    httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
    httpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;            
}
```

This code setup the service client to use Kerberos (Windows domain\username) authentication, but you can adjust the code to use any other authentication method.

PD: I am using Visual Studio 2022 and Net Core 6